# How to configure two wireless routers (Separated by distance) with the same network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, wireless-router, dhcp

Hello,

I have two wireless routers configured properly following my Internet Service Povider instructions.

Our house is composed of two floors and in each floor there is an ADSL socket, to which is connected each of my two routers (using ADSL filters).

My problem is that i can't get the two routers to work at the same time. In order for one of them to work properly and connect me to the internet , the other one should be shut down.

So, is there any kind of configuration that could be made in order to get the two routers to work properly at the same time?

**N.B:** The two routers are separated by distance and cannot be linked to each other (LAN-to-LAN or Lan-to-WAN).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something's gotta define your network, maybe it's a separate router or maybe it's one of the two wifi units. Any additional wifi units should then be configured as access points to the network. Apple Airports call this a "bridged network". Many vendors use slightly different terms for the same thing. It should be fairly do-able.

Answer (score 0):

## Turn off the Router.

Your consumer "Router" is not a router at all. It is in fact 3 devices in one.

- Network Address Translator (Router)
- Switch
- Wireless AP

There is no legitimate reason for a home user to use two routers on the same network (unless you understand concepts like VLAN/subnets/DMZ).

The chances are you want to use one of your "routers" as a Wireless AP.

If this is the case, there are a few steps you need to take.

1. Set the 2nd router up with a static IP, (one which isn't the same as the 1st router, but on the same subnet).
2. Disable the DHCP server on the 2nd router
3. Restart the 2nd router
4. Attach the 2nd router to the network
5. Profit
6. (Optionally) you can disable the NAT function

EDIT:

I noticed that you write that you want both routers to attach to the WAN via ADSL. That is impossible.

I would advise that you connect the two routers LAN-LAN possibly using [a pair of HomePlug devices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug)

Comment: Hello Aron thanks for your informative reply.
So which part of your answer should i consider?  before the "EDIT" of after the "EDIT"??

Comment: @AbdellahBakkach Depends on EXACTLY what you are trying to achieve.  You didn't make it clear how you wanted to connect them, why you wanted to connect them etc...You called your devices "routers" but I suspect now that they are actually "NAT/Switch/AP/xDSL modems". Can you confirm what ports you want to use?

Comment: Hello Aron Thanks for your concern.

1. I think when i said router i meant: "NAT/Switch/AP/xDSL modems" as you said ^^

Here are pictures of the two i have:

http://imgur.com/dVq72pi
http://imgur.com/qC6ncdE

2. Why do i want to connect them? Because wireless connection does not reach the second floor of our house and i need to put another "NAT/Switch/AP/xDSL modems" there and connect it to the ADSL socket:

http://i.imgur.com/ztmXAG9.png

Comment: So here are some use cases:
- Router 1 ON & Router 2 OFF : Floor 1 has wireless connection coverage and access to the internet.
- Router 1 OFF & Router 2 ON : Floor 2 has wireless connection coverage and access to the internet.
- Router 1 ON & Router 2 ON : Neither Floor 1 nor Floor 2 have internet connection.

Comment: @AbdellahBakkach Go with the HomePlugs to work as an ethernet cable between them and use the rest of the post to turn off the DHCP on one of them. Make sure that one also isn't connected to the xDSL line.